# Why I have to pass an instance of a class in a "modelMap.addAttribute" to the view in this case?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a doubt. I'm using spring MVC and playing around with code. When I get to this situation:

Inside the controller class I have this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo.html", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public String showFooJSP(ModelMap modelMap) {

        modelMap.addAttribute("dee",new Dee());

        return "/foo";
    }
```

And this method call the foo.jsp. Inside it, I want to remark only this lines:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="dee" action="/action.do" method="GET">
    <td>
        <form:hidden path="deeId">
    </td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Search"/></td>
</form:form>
```

---

When I comment the line "modelMap.addAttribute("dee",new Dee());" of the controller, it gives me this error when i want to access the jsp:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'dee' available as request attribute

I want to know why, because I want to understand why spring need me to send at least an instance of "dee" type in this case.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: How would it resolve `<form:hidden path="deeId">` without it?

Comment: I thought about that, but I didn't wanted to make assumptions about that. Because I thought that spring would figure it out, where to get the reference of the model and its attributes inside.

Comment: Model attributes are request attributes. If you have more than one request attribute, how do you expect Spring MVC to figure out what you mean without specifying its name?

Comment: hmm so In few words, Spring always needs the programmer to show somehow of which class/object I'm working on inside the jsp? So because of that I use the statement "modelMap.addAttribute("dee",new Dee());". If that's the case, the instance of "new Dee()" is just to inform Spring about that class?

Comment: Right, and given the `path="deeId"`, Spring MVC will look up a property named `deeId` on the model attribute and inject its value in the generated HTML.